# How to save HTTParty response to db?(Update!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

Need to save httparty response to db and call it in view file

this is what httrparty get

[image: enter]

in services folder/

```
 class ParserService
      include HTTParty
      API_KEY = '882e10dd2b474a23bb7a3efa85e66b61'.freeze
      base_uri 'https://newsapi.org/v2/'
      default_params fielsd: "title, description, ulr, content"
      format :json

      def self.top_headlines(country_name='us') 
        new(country_name).top_headlines
      end

      def initialize(country_name='us')
        @options = { query: { country: country_name, apiKey: API_KEY} }
      end

        def top_headlines 
          response = self.class.get("/top-headlines", @options)
          pars_json = response.parsed_response
          pars_json["articles"].each do |k|
            @source = ActiveModel::Source.create(google_id: k["id"], name: k["name"])

            @article = Article.create(title: k["title"], source_id: @source.id,
                                      description: k["description"], content: k["content"])

          end
        end  
    end
```

ArticleController

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController


    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end
end
```

and model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :source, class_name: "Source", optional: true
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :source_id, uniqueness: true 

end
```

and schema.rb

[image]

That what I done now
if try to save Article in (rails c) console have this error, validation

[image]

when try to comment validation it save but....it save empty fields

[image]

and I realy do not understand why it empy, when I call JSOn directlly, without saving to db, on view it show all what I need, but now I have this...
on index page

[image]

[image]

and in console later got errors

[image]

I can image how to fix this and what and where go wrong

Comment: Could you tell us where you stuck :)

Comment: @Manoj
articles are show on page now, but every time on refresh page  it call API method
I want save it to db and call it from db.
stuck on saving to db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what it looks like to me:

```rb
pars_json.each do |k|
  art = ParserService.new('us')
  res = response.body
  art.title = res["title"]
  art.save
end
```

this piece is where you're trying to save it to the DB? I don't think ParserService is a model you've created that reflects a table from your DB.

if you have the `Article` model that you're wanting to use to save each object parsed from API call you'd want to do something as such instead of the above:

```rb
pars_json.each do |k|
  article = Article.create(title: k["title"], k["description"]...)
end
```

Try to first print out what `k` is exactly and line up the object keys to correspond to the correct `Article` fields.

Again, to save to the DB, you need to use a model you've created that reflects a table on the DB. if you have the `articles` table on your DB where you'd like to save your API response data, then you should create instances of `Article` and save those.

Then in the controller it's just calling it by `@articles = Article.all` or whichever query you'd like to run to have your list of articles.

I'd recommend running the `ParserService` in a Background job to have the API fetch the data on a parallel process without having it affect too much the rails process

Comment: I think that what I need
but where exacly I should put this save method that it works?

I realy do not understud if it call somewhere or what, because now it do now save to DB anithing. 

If i take all code inside of class and put it in Article model it still don't work

Comment: it almost work
but get this error
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Source(#70117389054060) expected, got {"id"=>nil, "name"=>"Espn.com"} which is an instance of Hash(#47345000114540)

Comment: could you update your question with the code you try to ran which produced the 
 `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch`? I think it may be possibly you passing in the  `source_id` from the api call as a string inside of an integer.. for example: `(source_id: k['id'])` `k['id']`(the id coming from the api) should be coerced to an integer by doing `k['id'].to_i` .. but I can't verify this until you update :)

Comment: so when you `Article.create!` with your validation, you'll have a rollback that doesn't allow you to save it (first example) and in the second example it does save because you don't have a validation to verify if your `Article` needs the fields to be populated. when you create `Article.create!` you're also not adding any fields to it. you're not adding anything so the fields will be blank.. if you wanted to add fields you'd have to do `Article.create!(tittle: "This is my article title", description: "This is the description of the article)` and also include whatever other fields must be there.